# How to move the display Label on the object?

Tags: c#

There is a program showing the name of the character in the game. The problem is that the name appears in the legs, and I need on the character! (How to change the position of the tags above (over the head)?

```
OtherPlayerDecorator = new WorldDecoratorCollection(                
    new GroundLabelDecorator(Hud)
    {
        BackgroundBrush = Hud.Render.CreateBrush(255, 0, 0, 0, 0),
        BorderBrush = Hud.Render.CreateBrush(200, 0, 190, 255, 1),
        LabelFont = Hud.Render.CreateFont("tahoma", 6f, 255, 0, 190, 255, false, false, 128, 0, 0, 0, true),
    }
);
```

[image]

Comment: The code is not helpful. don't just crop a piece of code from your project.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: all code http://pastebin.com/nm4y5pKe

Comment: I think there used ASP!

Comment: I don't get it. Is this an addon to the game (as far as I know, Diablo III does not support addons) or a project working over images or similar?